# Xpages showing a cell table after field value is changing

Tags: xpages

In a `djTabPane` I put all the content in a table with 1 row and 1 column:

```
<xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane3" title="Valoare contract">

    <xp:table  id="CellVal"> ... </xp:table> </xe:djTabPane>
```

In this main table I have numerous tables. Certain table has only 2 rows. On the first row there is this field:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText23" value="#{Contr.vff1}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="CellVal">
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:inputText>
```

I want the next `<tr>` from this table to be rendered when this field is changing:

```
   <xp:tr>
        <xp:this.rendered>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:Contr.getItemValueString("vff1") != ""}]]>
        </xp:this.rendered>
                <xp:td>s</xp:td>
   </xp:tr>
```

But still the row isn;t shown. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you missing quotation marks after "vff1 ?

Comment: Nope, it was a typo mistake.

Comment: onchange event gets fired only if you leave edit field. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. No luck for me, could I use perhaps the rendered property inside the <xp:tr> tag? But I guess I will have the same result.

Comment: Rendered property "belongs" already to <xp:tr> the way you wrote it.

Comment: Like in all other cases too: extract your code into a simple XPage and play with it until it works. As long as you test with your complete XPage you might have influences from other elements.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann I see, I will give a try. Btw, if I'd rule the repeat controls element, I wouldn't use this kind of static table ... ;(

Comment: If you use a refreshId then use this id in your td element, too

Comment: I'm assume it's valid but it's weird to me to see your rendering code.  I always wrap that type of stuff up in an actual if statement  and return true or return false...

Comment: @DavidLeedy well it is javaScript, so it's working. hint: you don't have to use if statement returning true / false.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: add an Error control to your page you can see. The problem might be a failing validation.
Step 2: Strip the example down to a minimal problem
Step 3: consider a client side show routine instead of SSJS. Saves you the roundtrip.

Something like this (off my head) in a script block:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
    document.getElementById("#{inputText23}").addEventListener("onchange", function(){
       document.getElementById("#{give-the-tr-an-id}").className = "showup";
    });
});
```

Then use classes and CSS to show/hide it.